# Binding custom element in initial loading

Tags: data-binding, aurelia

In aurelia: I have a string interpulation over object property that works fine in the app.html - it shows number of accounts:

```
ALL ACCOUNTS (${userAccountsData.length})
```

In the initial loading, I see that the value changes after few milliseconds from 0 to the actual value (data is retrieving from the service), **but** - when trying to show aggregate data (count number of active accounts) over the same data in a template (custom element) - the data stays as 0 and **not updated** as the **userAccountsData.length**
*When refreshing again after the initial loading - the data is shown as it should be.
This is the custom element instance in the app.html:

```
<account-status-selection-bar accounts-data.bind="userAccountsData"></account-status-selection-bar>
```

And this is part of the HTML of the custom element itself:

```
<template>
<div ref="active" 
class="selection">${accountActivationDistribution.numberOfActiveAccounts}
```

This is the relevant part of the custom element VM:

```
"use strict";
import { bindable} from 'aurelia-framework';
export class accountStatusSelectionBar {
@bindable accountsData;

constructor() {
   this.accounts = [];
   this.accountActivationDistribution = { numberOfActiveAccounts: 0,
   numberOfInactiveAccounts : 0,
   numberOfTotalAccounts : 0
}
get activeAccounts() {
   var activeAccounts = this.accounts.filter(function(account) {
   return account.IsApproved;
  });
  return activeAccounts.length;
}
attached()//bind()
{
   this.accounts = this.accountsData;
   this.accountActivationDistribution.numberOfActiveAccounts =        
   this.activeAccounts
 }
```

In the app.js I use observerLocator - here is the code related to the working part of userAccountsData.length:

```
constructor() {
 this.userAccountsData = [];
 ....
 this.subscribe = this.observerLocator.getObserver(accounts, "all")
  .subscribe((value) => {
    if (!value)
      return;
    this.userAccountsData = value;
```

**A work around I found (although I'm not sure this is the best way) is to do the aggregation in the app.js (in the observer part) in object and bind the already aggregated object to the custom element - this is working. I'm still looking for the mentioned above solution.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the problem is you're binding `userAccountsData` to `accountsData` on your custom control; then assigning `this.accounts = this.accountsData`; and finally later you're reassigning `userAccountsData` in app.js.

Because `accounts` is not observing or bound to the original `userAccountsData`, it maintains the reference to the original array (which is set to an empty array) and never gets updated.

There is a race condition on refresh, where some cache probably means that `userAccountsData` gets the updated value before the binding occurs, which is why it works sometimes.

The solution is to remove some of the reassignment and just bind directly to `accounts` and forget the intermediate `accountsData`.

I created a [gist here](https://gist.run/?id=c23e654e5052b797dd8e92a524dd095c) showing the different behaviour.